# How to show the NavigationDrawer icon in the ActionBar with AppCompat Library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

I have a problem with the NavigationDrawer icon, I want it to be visible within the ActionBar. It is needed to show the user, that he can open the drawer in my app by swiping from the left edge of the screen. 
[image: android]

I use this code before without any problems, but in this application it isn't working well, I don't know what the problem can be. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    ArrayList<Integer> smIcon_adrs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    smIcon_adrs.add(R.drawable.sm_font);
    smIcon_adrs.add(R.drawable.sm_size);
    smIcon_adrs.add(R.drawable.sm_count);
    smIcon_adrs.add(R.drawable.sm_about);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> sm_adapter = new smIcoAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            smIcon_adrs);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(sm_adapter);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.hello_world, R.string.app_name) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("دعا عهد");
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("امکانات");
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START); 
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

and here:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_play:
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.actn_play);
            mp.pause();
        } else {
            updateProgressBar();
            mp.start();
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.actn_stop);
        }
        break;

    }
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    // menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: are u using ActionBarSherlock or stock ActionBar? would be great if you can share the code related to ActionBar

Comment: i use appcompat library .

Answer (score 1):

Here is someone with a similar problem, you might test the solution posted there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23332975/1738838.

According to that you are missing this method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```